# Loading the data in memory to get faster response

Tags: python, c++, linux, caching, in-memory

I am using svm classifier, which classify the data using learned model. Here is the command I execute:

```
./svm_classify input.txt modelrank > input.txt.entities
```

`svm_classify` - is the opensource classifier ([Link](http://svmlight.joachims.org/))

`input.txt` - input file that is to be classified.

`modelrank` - this is svm model for classification.  having 124MB. Trained using large dataset.

`input.txt.entities` - output file

but as `modelrank` is large file, 124mb. Loading everytime during new request for classification makes process slower.

Is there anyway so that it can be `In memory` so that it respond instantly while there's new request?

Comment: Did you write the code in svm_classify?

Comment: @lisu: no, it's opensource package, I am updating the link

Comment: Surely if svm_callisfy is an open source package that (1) that's an input file (2) is open source then (1) it won't take the data from memory as it stands (2) you could contribute to it so it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since editing the software would probably be a hassle, what you can do to speed things up is getting the file to RAM first. To do that you'd have to mount a partition stored in RAM, [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/).
This should reduce loading time noticably.

Comment: thanks you very much, I guess this is what I want. O go through that link. but after copying my file to ramcache, how can I use it for above scenario?

Comment: In similar way you're doing it right now - the only change will be path to model file - instead of modelrank you'd probably do sth like /mount/memcache/modelrank.For better results you can also copy binary to ramcache, or the whole thing and then use it as usuall. Make sure to write/copy your results to hard disk afterwards.

Comment: thank again, getting this error `cp: writing `/ramcache/modelrank': No space left on device
cp: failed to extend `/ramcache/modelrank': No space left on device
`

Comment: Maybe the disk you've created is too small? What does df say?

Comment: it says `/dev/ram1        65M   65M     0 100% /ramcache`

Comment: in `mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192` if I go above some limit it give error.

Comment: Yes, tehre is a limit to that value, but usually it's bigger than 128 MB. Otherwise, you may want to try using tmpfs from this [discussion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/creating-a-ram-disk-on-linux)

Comment: thanks again. As per the last ans on that link, do I need to copy modelrank file in `temp` directory